# Images similarity measure using Jeffrey’s Divergence (j Divergence)

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, statistics, software-implementation, distance-metrics

I need to reproduce the result of [Xu, Xiaocong, et al, 2016 paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0924271616304324) . Mutual information code already was done and work fine. Can anyone help me to write Jeffrey’s divergence code? Because the I use Jeffrey’s divergence function in [file exchange code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39275-histogram-distances), but I think it has an issue.

In the aforementioned paper the j-div is better because it has wider distance between correct result and wrong one, but in my case, the opposite happens, MI is better (see the image below).

Paper result:

[image]

My result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the paper the definition is given by:

[image]

All you need is to find a function which implements the Kullback Leibler Divergence and apply it twice (Will be inefficient).

In MATLAB you may use [`relativeEntropy()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/predmaint/ref/relativeentropy.html) or use [`getKullbackLeibler()`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/62981) which seems a decent implementation.

In the latter you may just replace `KLD = nansum( P .* log2( P./Q ) );` with `JLD = nansum( (P - Q) .* log2( P./Q ) );` for Jeffrey’s Divergence.